# How to connect to SharePoint 2013 on-premise using CSOM in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am aware that using CSOM in PowerShell we can connect to SharePoint Online from local machine, how can we connect to SharePoint 2013 on-premise using CSOM in PowerShell?

Note: I am using System.Net.NetworkCredential to get username and password for On-Premsie

**Used the below script, getting the errors while executing it.**

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

function OnPremises-Test {
    $siteUrl = "https://<>/"

    $clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
    $clientContext.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("myusername", "password")

    $web = $clientContext.Web 
    $clientContext.Load($web) 
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

Write-Host " Current web title is '$($web.Title)', $($web.Url)"

}

 OnPremises-Test
```

**Below are the errors:**

*Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
At C:\Users\v-krirao\Desktop\test.ps1:17 char:2
+     $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException*

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Patterns and Practices (PnP) contains a library of PowerShell commands ([PnP PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_powershell/pnp-powershell-overview)) that allows you to perform complex provisioning and artifact management actions towards SharePoint. The commands use CSOM and can work against *both* **SharePoint Online** and **SharePoint On-Premises**.

The advantage is code you have written can be simply replaced with one single commandlet.

Comment: I have a problem with PnP as I have to handover scripts to different environment where deployment will be taken by other people, cant ask them to install PnP cmdlets.

Comment: I understand you have to submit it to another environment. if possible, installing pnp can be done with just one commnand : "Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell2013" which you can be part of your script. Check at the beginning if PNP is installed. If not, run given command.

Comment: I was reticent at first to use the pnp but after some experimentation I think this is a useful and well documented framework.   It does not in itself answer the OP though.

Answer (score 0):

Although your code works for me on my 2013 site 
...Extensions\16\ISAPI... is not specific for SP2013 try the following;

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
```